# How to fix PHP saying boxes are empty

Tags: php, mysql

PHP saying theres nothing in the boxes when I put stuff in.

Tried putting `var_dump($_POST); die();` at the top of register.php and it showed what I put in the boxes

Not sure what's going on here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I've spent a while trying to figure this out.
Will login work aswell?

Thanks,
Jon

functions.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect(:-));

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors   = array(); 

// call the register() function if register_btn is clicked
if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    register();
}

// REGISTER USER
function register(){
    // call these variables with the global keyword to make them available in function
    global $db, $errors, $username, $email;

    // receive all input values from the form. Call the e() function
    // defined below to escape form values
    $username    =  e($_POST['username']);
    $email       =  e($_POST['email']);
    $password_1  =  e($_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2  =  e($_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Username is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($email)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($password_1)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
    }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

        if (isset($_POST['user_type'])) {
            $user_type = e($_POST['user_type']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$email', '$user_type', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['success']  = "New user successfully created!!";
            header('location: home.php');
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$email', 'user', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

            // get id of the created user
            $logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

            $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_id); // put logged in user in session
            $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');              
        }
    }
}

// return user array from their id
function getUserById($id){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $user;
}

// escape string
function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
}

function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="error">';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'<br>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}   


function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    header("location: login.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    login();
}

// LOGIN USER
function login(){
    global $db, $username, $errors;

    // grap form values
    $username = e($_POST['username']);
    $password = e($_POST['password']);

    // make sure form is filled properly
    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    // attempt login if no errors on form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
            // check if user is admin or user
            $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                header('location: admin/home.php');       
            }else{
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}

// ...
function isAdmin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

register.php

```
<?php 
    include('functions.php');
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register | Vex Radio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
</div>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <p><?php echo display_error(); ?></p>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_2">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="register_btn">Register</button>
    </div>
    <p>
        Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP to save the items in a DB and allow me to login

Comment: Show the definition of `e()` as that could be breaking everything

Comment: its in functions.php

```
function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
}
```

Comment: Did you verify it is working correctly?

Comment: its not I tried

Comment: Then that's your problem. The other code is irrelevant. You should be trying to figure out why *that* code is broken, not everything else around it.

Comment: You should be using pdo or mysqli prepared statements, then you don't need the e function anyway

Comment: `#register_btn` doesn't seem to have a value. Off the top of my head, I don't remember if that means it will be submitted with an empty value, or not submitted. If it's the latter, that's your problem.

Comment: Also, global variables are very poor form, and your SQL queries are vulnerable to injection. Escaping is not always enough. Use prepared statements.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THIS CODE ON A PRODUCTION APPLICATION**. Unless this is purely for academic purposes it's not worth using. If it is for academic purposes and you're trying to learn how to write a login system, you **must** learn how to store passwords securely. MD5 is worthless, it's a high-speed hash that can be cracked easily. You need to use a password-specific hash like Bcrypt which is what [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) does by default. This makes the password hashes very difficult to brute-force guess, giving your users considerable peace of mind.

Comment: Naive MD5 hashing produces identical hashes for identical passwords. This means people can use Google as a "rainbow table" to reverse lookup what passwords people have. For example, if a user had the password hash of `73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc` it would be trivial to hack their account.